# List of groups and users on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting

I am setting up a user group and user audit/review process. For this I am looking for a script that can easily generate a list of groups and the assigned users. E.g.:

```
Administrators/Administrator
Administrators/Account1
Administrators/Account2
SomeOtherGroup/Accounts2
```

Comment: Are you looking for domain groups or local computer groups? and do you have to worry about nested groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `net localgroups` to get a list of groups on the local machine, and `net user` to get a list of users.  You can then use `net user USERNAME` to get a list of groups that the user is in.  It will require a bit of scripting to put it all together though.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this text in a batch file:

```
  @echo off

  for /f "delims=*" %%a in ('dsquery user -name * -limit 12000^|dsget user -samid') do Call :ShowUser %%a
  goto :eof

  :ShowUser
    set usr=%*
    If "%usr%"=="dsget succeeded" goto :eof
    for /f "delims=*" %%b in ('dsquery user -name * -limit 12000^|dsget user -memberof^|dsget group -samid') do if NOT "%%b"=="dsget succeeded" Echo %usr%  %%b
```